# Is it possible to change PrimeFaces theme on the fly?

Tags: jquery-ui, jsf, primefaces

I have a multi-tenant system, the user is signed will have a custom theme in the application, I want to know if it is possible to change the theme "on the fly" after the user has signed. I'm new to Primefaces, thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primefaces already implements jQuery UI's [ThemeRoller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/).  In your web.xml you can define a context-param `primefaces.THEME` with a parm-value pointing to session-scoped backing bean.

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
    <param-value>#{FooBar.theme}</param-value>
</context-param>
```

See also: http://www.primefaces.org/primeui/themes.html

Comment: Maybe you should add link to http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/themeSwitcher.xhtml

Comment: @Mariah, hello, it´s been a while but, do you know a way of loading all primefaces themes in a drop down in the view. Right now I can switch themes dynamically, but I am populating the list manually, is there a way to populate the list of themes programmatically? thanks